# Is there a way to parameterise the right hand side of a filter evaluation in a curried function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, currying

I would like to convert the following to make it reusable / generic. Specifically I'm not sure what approach to take to parameterise the right hand side of the filter evaluation.

Here is what I have so far and this works for the use case below. I'm trying to convert the currying part to something like this...

```
const filterProcess = theFilter => theData => theFilter === ${dataBranch}.${dataLeaf}
```

My Current Working Use Case.

```
const hotelList = [
    {city: "London", hotel: 1},
    {city: "Prague", hotel: 1},
    {city: "London", hotel: 2},
    {city: "Prague", hotel: 2},
]

const isLocated = location => hotels => location === hotels.city

const hotelsIn = hotelList.filter(isLocated(location));

console.log(hotelsIn('London'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking an iterative approach, since `hotelsIn` needs to be a function, you want `isLocated` to return a function that accepts the location:

```js
const hotelList = [
    {city: "London", hotel: 1},
    {city: "Prague", hotel: 1},
    {city: "London", hotel: 2},
    {city: "Prague", hotel: 2},
]

const isLocated = location => hotel => location === hotel.city

const hotelsIn = location => hotelList.filter(isLocated(location));
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^

console.log(hotelsIn('London'))
```

Then we can generalize that by factoring out the property name (`city`):

```js
const hotelList = [
    {city: "London", hotel: 1},
    {city: "Prague", hotel: 1},
    {city: "London", hotel: 2},
    {city: "Prague", hotel: 2},
]

const isLocated = (name, value) => item => value === item[name]
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^       ^    ^^^^    ^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^^

const hotelsIn = (name, location) => hotelList.filter(isLocated(name, location))
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

console.log(hotelsIn('city', 'London'))
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^
```

If you wanted, you could add a `hotelsInCity` function:

```js
const hotelList = [
    {city: "London", hotel: 1},
    {city: "Prague", hotel: 1},
    {city: "London", hotel: 2},
    {city: "Prague", hotel: 2},
]

const isLocated = (name, value) => item => value === item[name]

const hotelsIn = (name, location) => hotelList.filter(isLocated(name, location))

const hotelsInCity = city => hotelsIn('city', city)

console.log(hotelsInCity('London'))
```

Comment: Hi T.J, much obliged. This worked and makes sense. I'm not a developer by trade but try to fit it in when I can. Thank you for the quick and concise answer.

Comment: Why not curry that function as well? `const hasProperty = name => value => obj => value === obj[name]; const isLocated = hasProperty('city'); const inLondon = isLocated('London');`

Comment: @Bergi - Heh, yeah, I did that too, as `hotelsInCity`. You can mix and spin this any way you want. :-)